# create-react-appでfaildと表示されました。

Tags: node.js, reactjs

以下を実行した時エラーが出ました。

```
create-react-app react_lessons
Creating a new React app in /var/www/html/react_lessons/react_lessons.

Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react-scripts...

npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.14
npm install --save-dev --save-exact react-scripts failed
```

コマンド実行してから30分以上たって上記エラーが出ました。

ディレクトリを確認すると一通りファイルは生成されていそうなのですが
package.jsonも自動生成されていたので確認したところ以下の記述しかありませんでした。

```
"name": "react_lessons",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true
```

react-scriptsのインストールが失敗しているのでしょうか。
こういった場合どのような解決方法がいいのでしょうか。

補足情報としてnpm install -g create-react-appを実行したときにエラーが発生し
sudoを付けて実行し直したところ実行できたという経緯があります。

Answer (score 0):

色々調べて試しているうちにとりあえず解決したのでメモしておきます。
おそらく`index.html`で読み込んでいる`react.js`、`reactdom.js`とbabelの`browser.min.js`の相性が
悪かった可能性が高そうです。

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
```

こちらで当方の環境ではうまくいきました。
根本的な原因などもし間違った情報を上げてしまっていたら申しわけありません。
お手数ですがご指摘いただけましたら幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

`create-react-app`のインストールに`sudo`を用いる必要はありません。`npm`はどのようにインストールしましたか？

```
$ which npm
/Users/<username>/.nodebrew/current/bin/npm
```

また、`/var/www/html/`でないディレクトリで試してみてください。

```
$ cd ~
$ npx create-react-app react-lessons
```